# мануальная сортировка mysql

Tags: mysql, сортировка

привет
Есть таблица где хранятся тексты. Динамичная таблица. Пользователь может добавлять сколько угодно записей. Надо чтобы пользователь также смог сам перетаскиванием определял порядок записей и сохранил текущее положение.

Подумал можно добавить order_id каждой записи с соответствующим значением и сортировать по order_id. Но здесь проблема в том что если пользователь будет изменять положение одной записи, то надо будет заново обновлять order_id для всех записей. А их может быть и 100. Поэтому думаю это не оптимальный вариант.

Comment: К написанному в ответе на тот вопрос можно добавить, что если вы двигаете именно мышкой т.е. за раз +-1 один элемент, то достаточно изменить 2 записи, поменяв между ними их order_id